# Django subject_slug Name error

Tags: python, django, slug

I am working on my homepage, but I get an error when I click on myworkandresearch.html. Is it related to template?

> NameError at / myworkandresearch /
>
> name 'subject_slug' is not defined

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template import loader, context
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Category, Subject, Article


# Create your views here.
def myworkandresearch(request):
    category_list=Category.objects.all()
    subjects=Subject.objects.filter(slug=subject_slug, subject__category__slug=category_slug)


    context={
        'categor_list':category_list, 
        'subjects':subjects
    }
    return render(request, 'myworkandresearch/myworkandresearch.html', context)


def category(request,category_slug):
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    subject=Subject.objects.filter(slug=subject_slug, subject__category__slug=category_slug)
    article=Article.objects.filter(slug=article_slug, subject__slug=subject_slug, subject__category__slug=category_slug)
    context = {
        'category_list': category_list,
        'article': article,
        'subject':subject
    }
    return render(request, 'myworkandresearch/category.html', context)
```

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195219/5644965 is not an answer, why you did not edit your question instead?

Comment: You already ask this question, and we told you the error is not related to your template, this is because `subject_slug` is not defined in your view, the error says it itself..  this line `subjects=Subject.objects.filter(slug=subject_slug`

Comment: @lemayzeur because i cant edit. İ was understand but why can i ?

Comment: can you show us, where you call these 2 views.. If you have a template, add it to your question, and please don't post it as an answer?

Comment: i understand you but i can't. why can i define @Lemayzeur

Comment: No worries, one last thing: you really want to learn this Framework. I suggest that you start with the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something). I would have liked to help you

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen your previous response. I can not assign the design template to the question. I have a lot of code and I get the error. So I threw it in response. Is the subject_slug part defined in html? @Lemayzeur

Comment: I don't know where it supposed to come from, because you are not able to provide info that we need to help you, sorry!

Comment: Is the required information in the model file? okey, thank u anywhere @Lemayzeur